# ¿Es posible abrir un p:dialog desde una página diferente en la que está creado?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy usando JSF 2.2 y PrimeFaces 5.3, lo que busco es reutilizar ciertos diálogos en unos formularios que tienen relación, pero no sé si esto sea posible. Aclaro que soy nuevo en este mundo de JSF.

Comment: Hola @JoseFelix, bienvenido a  SOes, podrías agregar lo que hayas intentado hacer hasta ahora? todo lo que incluyas en tu pregunta es bienvenido por los expertos y será mas fácil que te ayuden.

Answer (score 2):

¿Los diálogos son sólo informativos o están conectados a algún `ManagedBean`?

De ser sólo informativos puedes ayudarte de la librería `ui` de [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf).
Para esto debes crear el `dialog` en un archivo XHTML aparte que llamaremos en el ejemplo `dialog.xhtml`. El archivo sería así:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>No importa el titulo</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
        <p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40">
            <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
        </p:dialog>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

Y ahora lo puedes llamar libremente desde otro archivo XHTML de la siguiente manera:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Tu titulo</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <ui:insert name="dialog">
            <ui:include src="dialog.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </ui:insert>
        <p:commandButton value="Basic" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Sólo debes fijarte en el valor que le das al `widgetVar` para posteriormente llamarlo abajo.

En caso de que tus `dialog` tengan interacción con algún `ManagedBean`, creo que lo más correcto sería crear un `Bean` sólo para administrar los `dialog`.

Comment: Los dialogos serian de ambos casos segun se requiera. En el caso de interaccion con el managen bean esté que estructura deberia tener.